# mongodb : aggregate and $lookup with ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, objectid

using mongodb 3.4 through MEAN, I have two schemas:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    trim: true },
username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    trim: true },
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true }
},
{ collection: 'users'}
);
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

and the other one:

```
var followSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
username: {
   type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   ref: 'User'
},
   followers: [{
   type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   ref: 'User'
}],
following: [{
   type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   ref: 'User'
}]
},{   collection: 'follows'}
);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Follow', followSchema);
```

resulting (as an exemple) in below object when User A have followers and following:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("ae1d6f8..."),
   "username" : ObjectId("User A"),
   "followers" : [
       ObjectId("User B")
       ObjectId("User C")
    ],
   "following": [
       ObjectId("User B")
    ]
}
```

I would like to retrieve username of all followers and following. My not working query is:

```
Follow.aggregate([{
                $match: {
                    "username": user_id
                }
            },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        "from": "User",
                        "localField": "following",
                        "foreignField": '_id',
                        "as": "userFollowing"
                    }
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        "from": "User",
                        "localField": "followers",
                        "foreignField": '_id',
                        "as": "userFollowers"
                    }
                }, {
                    $project: {
                        "username": 1,
                        "userFollowers": 1,
                        "userFollowing": 1
                    }
                }
            ]).exec(function (err, doc) {
                console.log(doc);
                rest.json({
                    'state': true,
                    'msg': 'Follow list',
                    'doc': doc
                })
            })
```

This results of empty array of userFollowing & userFollowers:

```
[ { _id: 5aeca47e600ff8f00617ac05,
    username: 5ae1ee337863273c0adac1d7,
    userFollowing: [],
    userFollowers: [] } ]
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Okay. Rather than showing things like `ObjectId("User B")`, instead show us some "real documents" that you actually expect to be matching each other. Show the documents as they appear from the `mongo` shell. Not console log output, and not screenshots from Robomongo or Compass. The `mongo` shell is the thing that will show the documents as "text" form you can copy into your question and show us the correct data and types.

Comment: Probably more of a "future tip" really because your actual problem appears to be that `"from": "User"` from be `"from": "users"` or even `"from": User.collection.name` if you actually have the `User` model loaded in scope. MongoDB does not know what the "Model Name" is, and it needs the "collection name" as it actually appears on the server. By default your `"User"` **model** is the `"users"` **collection**.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are right! I changed "from":  "users" and it works.